Simulating the design of the Google Earth Pro using the GEE (Google Earth Engine)
Google Earth Pro (GEP) has the ability to view historical high-detail space imagery. In addition, there is a possibility to prepare some design, for example:

satellite data acquisition
north arrow
copyright info
Google logo

Can I replicate this design using Google Earth Engine (GEE) or is it technically impossible?
The question is asked because I don't really understand the GEE capabilities and before I start poking around in the manual I want to ask the experts already working with this engine.
I found an answer from two years ago that says you can't save high-resolution images available in GEP with GEE. Is this still true?

